# How to configure stderr from nc?

Tags: nc, connectivity, macos

I would like to check port connections with `nc` and forward the result to a text file.

`stdout` works fine. `stderr` is empty, if you don't use `-v` (which I dont want), so I would like to configure the error output like `Servername: no connection`

`nc` is version v1.10-41+b1.

Here's the command

```
nc -z -G 5 $Servername $Portname >> telnet_log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Can you [provide an example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/554214/edit) of your situation, please.

Comment: My `nc` (v1.10-41+b1) prints this message to stderr.

Comment: Here's the command:
nc -z -G 5 $Servername $Portname >> telnet_log.txt 2>&1

Answer (score 1):

`nc` on macOS exits with a non-zero exit status if it fails to connect to a host.  You can use this fact in an `if`-statement to output an error message of your own:

```bash
if ! nc -z -G 5 "$server" "$port"; then
    printf '%s: no connection (port=%s)\n' "$server" "$port" >&2
fi >>nc-results.log 2>&1
```

This would add whatever data `nc` produces on standard output to the file `nc-report.log` if it succeeded in connecting, but would add your own custom error if it did not connect.

Comment: Thanks, this is much nicer than what I figured out meanwhile:
nc -z -G 5 $Servername $Portname >> nc_log.txt 2>&1;
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo $Servername": No connection" >> $nc_log; fi